# check an array value whether its exists or not in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a php code like this.

```
<?php 
      $books = get_group('books');
      if($books){
      $booksfilter = "";
      foreach($books as $book){
        $booksfilter .= "<ul class=\"books\">";
        $booksfilter .= "<li><a href='".$book['books_image'][1]."' >image</a></li>";
        $booksfilter .= "<li>".$book['books_image_title'][1]."</li>";
        $booksfilter .= "<li>".$book['books_image_description'][1]."</li>";
        $booksfilter .= "</ul>";
         }
        echo $booksfilter; 
       } ?>
```

The code working fine. My problem is I have some problem while giveing css padding for li elements. It creates empty space when thearray has no value.  So can anyone tell me how to check whether the value exists or not.

I mean i want something like this

```
if value exists ($book['books_image_description'][1])
{
    $booksfilter .= "<li>".$book['books_image_description'][1]."</li>";
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($book['books_image_description'][1]) {
   ...
}
```

If this is a string and in most of the other cases, casting to boolean will do the job.

`boolean` cast of an empy string is equal to `false`
if key does'n exist it will be a null pointer, which casted to boolean is also `false`.

so you have 2 at the price of a 1 ... won't insert the `li` if key doesn't exist and if exist and its value is an empty string - which I think is you idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use the array_key_exists function

```
if(array_key_exists(1, $book['books_image_description']))
{
    ...
}
```